# Why does PDO rowCount() return 0 after UPDATE a table without modifying the existing data?

Tags: php

I am reading a tutorial on how to insert and update data into a MySQL table using PHP, the code is listed below. My problem is when i click update but I have not modified any data, rowCount() returns 0 and breaks the code.

My question is, If I am simply updating the database with the same values that are in the database, why does rowCount() return zero? My thoughts were that even though it was the same data it would be inserted anyway and return a count of the updated rows? I am guessing that it check the data before it try's the update? Can anyone shed some light on this for me and suggest a workaround? I have been starring at the code for hours and have been unable to come up with anything, thanks.

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/connection.inc.php');
// initialize flags
$OK = false;
$done = false;
// create database connection
$conn = dbConnect('write', 'pdo');
if (isset($_GET['article_id']) && !$_POST) {
    // prepare sql query
    $sql = 'SELECT article_id, title, article FROM blog WHERE article_id = ?';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // bind the results
    $stmt->bindColumn(1, $article_id);
    $stmt->bindColumn(2, $title);
    $stmt->bindColumn(3, $article);
    // execute query by passing array of variables
    $OK = $stmt->execute(array($_GET['article_id']));
    $stmt->fetch();
}
// if form has been submitted, update record
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    //prepare update query
    $sql = 'UPDATE blog SET title = ?, article = ? WHERE article_id = ?';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // execute query by passing array of variables
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['title'], $_POST['article'], $_POST['article_id']));
    $done = $stmt->rowCount();
}
// redirect page on sucess or if $_GET['article_id'] not defined
if ($done || !isset($_GET['article_id'])) {
    header('Location: http://localhost/PHP_Solutions/admin/blog_list_pdo.php');
    exit();
}
// store error message if query fails
if (isset($stmt) && !$OK && !$done) {
    $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
    if (isset($error[2])) {
        $error = $error[2];
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Update Blog Entry</title>
<link href="../styles/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Update Blog Entry</h1>
<p><a href="blog_list_pdo.php">List all entries </a></p>
<?php if (isset($error[2])) {
    echo "<p class='warning'>Error: $error[2]</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($error);
    echo '</pre>';
}
if ($article_id == 0) { ?>
    <p class="warning">Invalid request: record does not exist.</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input name="article_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $article_id; ?>">
  <p>
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input name="title" type="text" class="widebox" id="title" value="<?php echo htmlentities($title, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="article">Article:</label>
    <textarea name="article" cols="60" rows="8" class="widebox" id="article"><?php echo htmlentities($article, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Entry" id="update">
  </p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> My question is, If I am simply updating the database with the same values that are in the database, why does rowCount() return zero?

rowCount is counting the *affected* rows by a query. As you haven't changed anything, there are zero affected rows.

> [PDOStatement->rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) — Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement

Comment: but i am inserting the same data back into the rows, there is data there it is just the same data. How does it know the difference? Thanks

Comment: You aren't inserting, you're updating. There's a big difference, and SQL servers are intelligent enough to know whether they had to do any work or not. If you don't change the data in a row, it can hardly be deemed 'affected'.

Comment: how do you recommend i check to see if the data has not been modified? Thanks

Comment: If the data hasn't been modified, the rowCount will be zero. If the data was modified, the rowCount will be one or higher. If there was an error, rowCount will be null or false or something non-zero.

Comment: ok, so i just need to do another check and see if rowCount is greater than zero after the update, if not the data was the same and show the form again. Thanks for helping me understand and clarify.

Answer (score 12):

It has nothing to do with PHP - it's just how MySQL works.

[MySQL documentations says:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)

> For `UPDATE` statements, the affected-rows value by default is the number of rows actually changed. If you specify the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag to `mysql_real_connect()` when connecting to `mysqld`, the affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by the WHERE clause.

Comment: I appreciate it, i didnt understand thats how it worked. Thanks

Comment: PDO version: `$connection = new PDO($data_source, $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));`

Comment: @jave.web comment is the answer I was looking for

Comment: This is the best answer! Thanks @jave.web

Comment: @jave.web Thank you for the tricks ...

Answer (score 4):

When you're using the UPDATE statement, and you submit the same values that are in database, it will always return zero, because it doesn't affected any row.

A way to resolve this problem is:

```
$done = $stmt !== false ? true : false;
```

What i did?
I did that:

```
if($stmt !== false){
    $done = true;
} else{
    $done = false;
}
```

Because if **rowCount() is zero**, but **$stmt** has executed **without errors**, **$stmt** was executed, but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's how MySQL works and has nothing intrinsically to do with the PDO extension; performing a regular mysql query would produce the same results.  There is a workaround I found using the mysql functions, although I'm not sure if you can do anything similar with a PDO object.

```
$q = 'UPDATE etc...';
$r = mysql_query($q, $con);
$info = mysql_info(); // Returns info about last query.

list($matches, $changed, $warnings) = sscanf($matched, "Rows matched: %d Changed: %d Warnings: %d");

if ($matches > 0) {} // etc
```

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thanks i have both mysqli and pdo versions going, ill try that out