# PHP+MySQL website (localhost) working with netbeans xdebug, but NOT ALONE

Tags: php, sql-update, xdebug

Okay, this may sound off-topic, but I want to know if someone have had similar experience and if they found the problem/solution.

*Sorry this post has grown more like self try-and-error raportting, cause no one have answered. I have added status updates of problem solving in bottom of question.*

**For a moment the problem seems to be my database update query.**

I'm developing PHP+MySQL website on netbeans 7.3. + XAMPP. Everything was working fine. No **suddenly my log-in form** (suppose to save some $_SESSION variables and redirect to page) **is not working**.

Strange thing is that **when I debug with Netbeans + Xdebug all goes fine**. Session variables are set and page forwarded correctly.

**Question: Does someone faced similar problem? Has anyone idea what could be going wrong?**

I only can suppose something in system is set differently when I run xdebug. (But the exact(?) same log-in was working fine few days ago).

I have tried lot of things (many many hours but most of them don't come to my mind now). I tried to move the page on remote server and same behavior continues.

(If you want more info ask and I'll edit.)

Hope someone has ideas!

EDIT: I think has something to do with my php-session variables. I realized that while Xdebug the site starts with empty php-session variables, so it does use/get same ones it normally has (?)

The code is creating sessions to database, but it does not get to the next step to set the php-session variables. (Check out the place in index.php marked as /* HERE IS THE PLACE */

Okay. HERE IS STRIPPED CODE (working with netbeans+xdebug, not alone):

index.php:

```
<?php

//Open PDO connection to MySQL server: $db_con 
$db_connection = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test-login/db.php';
require $db_connection;

session_start();

//******************************************************************************
//Helping functions
function convert_time_to_utc_date ($UNIX_timestamp) {
    return gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $UNIX_timestamp);
}
//******************************************************************************
// Function to authenticate user with username and password. returns FALSE if not authenticated and TRUE if successful authentication
function authenticate_username_password($db_con, $usernm, $passwd)
{
    try {
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id, hashed_pwd, COUNT(*) AS usercount FROM gui_users WHERE username=? AND not_in_use = 0 AND deleted = 0");
        $stmt->execute(array($usernm));

        if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if($row['usercount'] == 1){
                if(crypt($passwd, $row['hashed_pwd']) == $row['hashed_pwd']){
                    $user_id = $row['id'];                        

                    session_regenerate_id(true);
                    $new_session_id = session_id();
                    $remote = true;
                    $datenow = convert_time_to_utc_date(time());

                    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO gui_sessions (session_id,user_id,starttime_UTC,lastused_UTC,remote) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->execute(array($new_session_id, $user_id, $datenow, $datenow, $remote));

                    return $user_id;
                }            
            }
        }

        return FALSE;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

//******************************************************************************
//Function to get user roles
function get_user_roles(PDO $db_con, $user_id)
{
    try {
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT role_id, role_last FROM gui_users WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return array('max_role_id' => $row['role_id'], 'last_role_id' => $row['role_last']);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

//******************************************************************************
// Function to handel sessions, log in and log out
function authenticate(PDO $db_con) {

    //********************
    // If action is LOG IN
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'login') {
        if (!isset($_POST['username']) or $_POST['username'] == '' or !isset($_POST['passwd']) or $_POST['passwd'] == '') {
            $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'Please fill in both fields';
            return FALSE;
        }

        $user_id = authenticate_username_password($db_con, $_POST['username'], $_POST['passwd']);


        if ($user_id !== false && $user_id > 0) {
            $_SESSION['reloadcounter'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $_SESSION['user_def_page'] = 1; //get_user_default_page($db_con, $user_id);

            $user_roles = get_user_roles($db_con, $user_id);
            $_SESSION['max_role_id'] = $user_roles['max_role_id'];
            $_SESSION['sel_role_id'] = $user_roles['last_role_id'];

            $goto = isset($_POST['goto']) ? $_POST['goto'] : HTTPS_SERVER;
            header('Location: ' . $goto);
            exit;
        } else {
            $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'Wrong username or password!';
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    //*********************
    // If action is LOG OUT
    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout') {
        $user_ses_id = session_id();
        try {
            $stmt = $db_con->prepare("DELETE FROM gui_sessions WHERE session_id=?");
            $stmt->execute(array($user_ses_id));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            log_error('PDO_CONN', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), TRUE, $db_con);
        }
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        unset($_SESSION['reloadcounter']);
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_def_page']);
        unset($_SESSION['max_role_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['sel_role_id']);

        $goto = isset($_POST['goto']) ? $_POST['goto'] : HTTPS_SERVER;
        header('Location: ' . $goto);
        exit;
    }

    //************************************
    // If no action see if user logged in
    $user_ses_id = session_id();
    $datenow = convert_time_to_utc_date(time());

    try {
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE gui_sessions SET lastused_UTC=? WHERE session_id=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($datenow, $user_ses_id));
        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION['reloadcounter']);
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
            unset($_SESSION['user_def_page']);
            unset($_SESSION['max_role_id']);
            unset($_SESSION['sel_role_id']);
            return FALSE;
       }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        log_error('PDO_CONN', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), TRUE, $db_con);
        if (DEBUG_ON) {
            echo 'SESSION UPDATE FAILED<br>';
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}

//******************************************************************************
//SESSION CONTROL
if (!authenticate($db_con)) {
    include 'login.html.php';
    exit();
}

include 'page.html.php';
?>
```

login.html.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="login-error"><?php if(isset($loginError)) { echo $loginError; } else { echo '&nbsp;'; } ?></p>
        <form id="login" action="" method="POST" name="login">
            <label for="username">Username:</label><br />
            <input name="username" type="text" size="40" value="" tabindex="0" /><br />
            <label for="passwd">Password:</label><br />
            <input name="passwd" type="password" size="40" value="" tabindex="1" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="goto" value="https://localhost/test-login/"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login"/>
            <input type="submit" class="button login" value="Login" tabindex="2"/><br />
        </form>
        <div><?php echo '<pre>' . var_dump($_SESSION) . '</pre>'; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

page.html.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Hello world!</h1>
            <?php echo '<pre>' . var_dump($_SESSION) . '</pre>'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I have track the error more and it seems that while Xdebuging the $_POST variables are okay, but standalone PHP interpreter is losing them some how.

Strange is also that I create the session to database inside if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login') and the php does not seem to get in there but it is able to Insert the session in database inside that if clause.

EDIT: Braking this till very peaces helped me to found one big mistake which still should not affect to the ACTUAL problem but made it much more harder to found.

Cause I have forgot to add curly brackets to if-else in the end of authenticate, the function always unset the session variables. In the beginning I thought that the function is not able to set them but it's actually unsetting them after redirection to "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']". Anyway this should not happen if the UPDATE gui_session statement would work. But it made it much harder to see where is the problem. Here is the correction for index.php:

```
//************************************
// If no action see if user logged in
$user_ses_id = session_id();
$datenow = convert_time_to_utc_date(time());

try {
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE gui_sessions SET lastused_UTC=? WHERE session_id=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($datenow, $user_ses_id));
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['reloadcounter']);
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_def_page']);
        unset($_SESSION['max_role_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['sel_role_id']);
        return FALSE;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    log_error('PDO_CONN', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), TRUE, $db_con);
    if (DEBUG_ON) {
        echo 'SESSION UPDATE FAILED<br>';
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

The problem is that this update fails. But i have no idea why.

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("UPDATE gui_sessions SET lastused_UTC=? WHERE session_id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($datenow, $user_ses_id));
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

If I try in php myadmin:

```
UPDATE gui_sessions 
SET lastused_UTC='2013-08-04 12:00:00' 
WHERE session_id='03dfgpiu1jl8idcjf191hqv4m2'
```

It affects 0 row, but if i do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM gui_sessions
WHERE session_id='03dfgpiu1jl8idcjf191hqv4m2'
```

It returns 1 row

Comment: Show us some code. We need to see where is the problem!

Comment: Like I said it's quite bunch of code but I can try to make an example. But I can not understand how it can be code problem if it works with xdebug. More I like to know if someone faced similar situation (page works only with xdebug) and what was the problem/solution.

Comment: I added stripped code example. While debugging this i realized that (maybe) debug session starts without "normal session variables" I have on my local host. I my opinion this should not affect anything, cause the page is not working even if I start with fresh browser/session.

Comment: Problem solved. It still would be nice to know why Xdebug behaved like it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Problem solved. I'll leave the answer here if someone somehow runs to similar problem. I still don't know what the Xdebug did to hide this problem.

The problem was that I was trying to authenticate user by updating the last_used field in database session table. I assumed that if query is able to update that field the session must be valid. So I check if sql update last_user rows affected equals to 1, then users php-session-id is in session table. Problem is that MySQL returns 0 rows affected if the field has already the value that is updated ["reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6237272/2628285). And in my case that's of course true, cause the session last_update field is just created in log in procedure.

BUT it was very painful to find the problem cause Xdebug was doing something very strange there and after 0 rows affected update query it jumped out of the function without going to the else statement of the if-clause where I check if the number of affected rows equals to 1.

Comment if you have idea why Xdebug was behaving this way.

Comment: This usually happens to me when there are custom error handlers involved.  Not sure if this applies to your situation.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with custom error handler. Now when I think this more there is no more secrets behind. The reason why it works with Xdebug, was that it stops every load to wait run so in update the new "last_used_UTC" is different so row affected works like i assumed. I tried (incorrect) use UPDATE "last_used_UTC" field to see if user is logged in (if row affected -> user logged in). Without Xdebug there is no stop between creating new session to db table and then updating "last_used_UTC" so Rows affected returns ZERO and "if-updated" went to else case and unset the session variables